# How to get an auto-sorting TableView?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a TableView with a list of items (Transaction) and want it to sort, so that all positive values are above the negative ones. This is the only requirement.

What I have until now:

```
expensesTableView.sortPolicyProperty().set(
    new Callback<TableView<Transaction>, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean call(TableView<Transaction> param) {
        Comparator<Transaction> c = (a, b) -> {
            if (a.getValue().contains("-") ^ b.getValue().contains("-")) { //getValue() returns a String
                return a.getValue().contains("-") ? 1 : -1;
            }
            return 0;
        };
        FXCollections.sort(expensesTableView.getItems(), c);
        return true;
    };
});
```

This wasn't my idea, I found this on the net, so don't ask if it looks like a strange way to achieve that. The real problem is, that the table doesn't sort on its own when a new item is added/edited/deleted. I need to click the header 3 times and then it does what I want.
How can I have a list that is always sorted correctly?

I tried adding a ChangeListener and sort on change. But besides that this is an ugly way to do that, it didn't even work... I'm at the end of ideas.

Comment: `expensesTableView.sort();` doesn't work?

Comment: @iMan: I tried that and got a StackOverFlowException before. No that you told me, I saw that this lead to an infinite loop since a listener was listening to changes and the sorting seems to fire such an event, so sorting -> calculateValues() -> sorting() -> ....  Thank you :) I thought the sort policy will keep the list automatically sortet. That's a bit confusing.

Comment: Do you need to override the sort policy? Can't you just set your comparator on a SortedList wrapping your ObservableList, then bind the comparator to the table as outlined in the javadoc for TableView?

Comment: @Geoff: I did that. But this is seriously the better approach? TableView.setitems(new SortedList(tableView.getitems()))? Looks a bit strange for such a basic feature. Of course, the comparator needs to be set too.

Comment: The sort policy is only applied when the user uses the column headings, and you probably get the StackOverflow error when using the listener because it is responding to the re-ordering of the items, rather than just addition and removal. My proposal was a bit off, I'm going to put up an answer with an example that seems to work.

Comment: It already works now. What you say about the listener was correct. Let's see what you come up with. :)

Comment: @TrudleR Great to know that it worked out for you. You can self-answer with what you did to fix. It will help other people visiting this question.

Answer (score 2):

The bitwise OR in the comparator didn't work in my tests, so I've changed it to a normal one, and it's also not checking for change in the value of items from the list.

I wonder if it might be more efficient to do a numeric check rather than a String check, negatives could still sort out below, but I guess the conversion might cost more?

My first idea with SortedList in the comments was actually related to keeping the original sorted order, to be restored after the user has changed the sort, so was off the mark.

Edited to add: Just to clarify, it's the act of keeping the source list sorted that keeps the table list sorted.

```
public class TestApp extends Application {

    private int c;
    private ObservableList<TestTransaction> sortedOL;
    private final Comparator<TestTransaction> comp = (TestTransaction a, TestTransaction b) -> {
        if (a.getValue().contains("-") || b.getValue().contains("-")) {
            return a.getValue().contains("-") ? 1 : -1;
        }
        return 0;
    };

    private TableView<TestTransaction> tableView;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        ArrayList<TestTransaction> rawList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
            int v = i * 3;
            if (v % 2 > 0) {
                v = v * -1;
            }
            c = i;
            rawList.add(new TestTransaction(Integer.toString(v), "Item " + c));

        }

        sortedOL = FXCollections.observableArrayList(rawList);
        sortedOL.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends TestTransaction> c1) -> {
            if (c1.next() && (c1.wasAdded() || c1.wasRemoved())) {
                FXCollections.sort(sortedOL, comp);
            }
        });
        FXCollections.sort(sortedOL, comp);

        tableView = new TableView<>(sortedOL);

        TableColumn<TestTransaction,String> valCol = new TableColumn<>("Value");
        valCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("value"));
        TableColumn<TestTransaction,String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("name"));
        tableView.getColumns().setAll(valCol, nameCol);

        BorderPane tpane = new BorderPane();

        Button btnAdd = new Button("Add");
        btnAdd.setOnAction(a -> {addTransaction();});

        ToolBar tb = new ToolBar(btnAdd);
        tpane.setTop(tb);

        tpane.setCenter(tableView);

        tpane.setPrefSize(600, 600);

        Scene scene = new Scene(tpane, 600, 600);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private void addTransaction() {
        c++;
        int v = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
        if (v % 2 > 0) {
            v = v * -1;
        }
        sortedOL.add(new TestTransaction(Integer.toString(v), "New Item " + c));
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}

public class TestTransaction {

    private String value;

    private String name;

    public TestTransaction(String value, String name) {
        this.value = value;
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the value
     */
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

If you want to use SortedList, meaning you could inline the comparator:

```
sortedOL = FXCollections.observableArrayList(rawList);
SortedList sorted = new SortedList(sortedOL, comp);
tableView = new TableView<>(sorted);
```

Comment: This example has nothing to do with a `SortedList`, right? I thought, that's what you are aiming for, because I also tried that.

Comment: You can get rid of the listener and use a SortedList as well, both are valid. The SortedList will do the listening and call sort for you:
SortedList sorted = new SortedList(sortedOL, comp); and then assign this to the tableView. You still need to add any items to the original ObservableList (sortedOL) as SortedList doesn't have an add method.

Comment: I give you a +1 for the effort, thank you! :) I tried it out yesterday and it worked. I'm still not sure if there is a best practice. Using a sorted list with a comparator as wrapper or using the `setSortPolicy()` way.

Comment: Thanks TrudleR. I found this: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2013-February/006194.html which gives some insight into the thinking behind it all. It seems that setting the sort policy is the only way to change the comparator on the TableView, so it might be the preferred method.